# how to pull one row and update boolean value in a column on that row using python and postgres?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a table with 100+ rows. Using Python I'm trying to get the first row preform some action on column A and update column B to true once done.

Then I would like to go to the next row and repeat this process.
current code

```
def _down():
     params = config()
     connection = psycopg2.connect(**params)
     req = ("BEGIN;")
     req2 = ("SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE col2 = False LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;")  
     cursor = connection.cursor()
     cursor.execute(req), cursor.execute(req2)
     data = cursor.fetchall()
     connection.commit()
     cursor.close(), connection.close()
```

I have a query that updates column b to true but it does it for the entire column rather than the specific row

```
req3 = ("update tablename set col2 = True")
```

Comment: Solved my own issue..
req3 = ("UPDATE table_name set col2 = True where id = %s;", (data))
for anyone who's new like me

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.